# Let's make the [new-gm] tag wiki useful

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Since we're keeping [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm), at least for now, we should fix up its (empty!) tag wiki. What should it say? Especially, what usage guidance should it include?

So that it's immediately useful I've already given it a wiki roughly in-line with my understanding of [the on/off-topic discussion about it](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4869/burninate-new-gm-tag). But it's very provisional! I just made some things up. Consider this question both a peer-review of that proposed tag wiki and as a place to brainstorm what it should say.

(As a bonus, figuring out what it should say in order to be most useful might be a step along the way to figuring out if there's a better tag for such questions.)

Answer (score 2):

For an idea of what kind of material I think should be in here, this is the first draft of the wiki and excerpt I've come up with.

Main features:

1. Tries to emphasise that this isn't for just being new, it's for problems that are inextricably *about* being new.

   This is hard to get across except with examples, I think, so it's the weakest part of the draft. But I think it's important to address somehow? Pointing people to alternatives later is part of showing what *isn't* inherently about being a new GM.
2. Points people away from using [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm) and toward using a plain system tag if they just have a rules question.
3. Lists some of the other more specific tags that c/should be used instead.

   I based the list on ones askers have commonly used along with [new-gm] mistags, as well as a few that it occurred to me should maybe get used more often.

Exerpt:

> Questions about becoming or tutoring a game master (GM) serving for the first time. Use this only when the question's inherently about being new, not simply as a descriptor of your skill level whilst handling a situation.

Wiki:

> For asking questions about the problems inherent in someone being new
>   to the game master (GM) role.
>
> ## Tagging guidance
>
> Use this tag when the problem is *inherently* about being new to
>   GMing, not just when the problem is caused by or the result of being
>   new to GMing.
>
> If the problem is about some other aspect of running roleplaying
>   games, and being new to GMing is why you don't know the answer,
>   *don't* use [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm). Instead, use a tag that describes the problem you're experiencing. In particular, questions about how a game
>   works should have the tag for that game system, and don't need this
>   tag.
>
> If in doubt, leave it out!
>
> ### Other subject tags
>
> There are a few other tags useful to someone who is new to RPGs; tags that are more  specific, and
>   when they apply they should be used instead of [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm):
>
> - [system-introduction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-introduction) — For questions about how to learn or teach a particular game or system. (Not used when just asking for
>     rules clarifications.)
> - [gm-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-techniques) — For questions about or asking for *specific* techniques to achieve *specific* effects, used while GMing.
> - [gm-preparation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-preparation) — For questions about preparing yourself and your materials for a game session.
> - [campaign-development](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign-development) — Whether a new or experienced GM, preparing a campaign is a whole topic on its own.
> - [adventure-writing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-writing) — Everyone is new to designing/writing adventures at some point, even experienced GMs.
> - [problem-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-gm) — For asking questions about a GM who may be causing or connected to conflicts in the gaming group, regardless of
>     whether the GM is new or not. See also [group-dynamics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-dynamics).
> - [group-dynamics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-dynamics) — Use this tag if you're trying to figure out how to pick your GM or how to manage changing GMs.

Comment: Are there any forms of emphasis for the excerpt that can emphasise the distinction? As it stands, a quick read will skip over the "about being new" distinction.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton The first few lines are the weakest part I think. Any way anyone can think of to make the distinction more obvious is very welcome. It's clearer after reading down, I think, but not everyone will.

Comment: People don't tend to read, or exert much effort on the 'net. The non-power users who need this guidance are likely to be the same ones who don't understand what a tag wiki is, nor how to get to it. They're one of the most obscure site features! If there's important guidance, we need to have something pithy to say in the summary itself.

Comment: I've made an attempt at adding that summary. @SevenSidedDie I think the problem with the phrase _"Use this tag when the problem is inherently about being new to GMing, not just when the problem is caused by or the result of being new to GMing."_ is simply that all problems inherently about being new to GMing _are_ also problems caused by or the result of being new to GMing!

Comment: I was going to write "not simply as a descriptor of your skill level whilst handling a problem that arose because of your lack of experience in GMing" - but again, lots of [the _good_ new-gm questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4870/1204) are problems that arose because of a lack of experience in GMing. Not sure where the line can be drawn and succinctly expressed. (This feels like a case where if we can't explain it simply, we don't understand it well enough yet.)

Comment: *"This feels like a case where if we can't explain it simply, we don't understand it well enough yet."* Yeah, working on this gives me that feeling too. It makes me think there must be a better tag, but what it could be is similarly not clear yet.